# Why does svg <use xlink:href="#"/> referencing an element with clip-path not work?

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path, grunt-svgstore

When implementing an SVG sprite, an `<svg>` element is created and svg elements are referenced via the `<use>` element. The containing `<svg>` element is then hidden using `style="display: none;"`

The clip-Path attribute does not render, but the path does. This leaves my path looking different from how I want it to.

How do I use an svg `<use xlink:href="#"/>` referencing an element with clip-path?

*I used grunt-svg-store to create my svg sprite, but have simplified this example for Q&A format https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/*

```
<svg id="svg-test" style="display: none;">
  <clipPath id="my-clip-1">
    <circle id="circle-1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
  </clipPath>
  <path id="svg-test-reference" clip-path="url(#my-clip-1)" d="M10-39.288h80v80H10z" />
</svg>

<!-- Reference SVG <path> by ID with Use -->

<svg class="svg-item" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <use xlink:href="#svg-test-reference" />
</svg>
```

[Live example on Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/itsjustluck/pen/WvvMXg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `<svg style="width:0; height:0;">` instead of `<svg style="display: none;">` to hide the sprite.

```
<!-- SVG element  -->

<svg id="svg-test" style="width:0; height:0;">
  <clipPath id="my-clip-1">
    <circle id="circle-1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
  </clipPath>
  <path id="svg-test-reference" clip-path="url(#my-clip-1)" d="M10-39.288h80v80H10z" />
</svg>

<!-- Reference SVG <path> by ID with Use -->

<svg class="svg-item" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <use xlink:href="#svg-test-reference" />
</svg>
```

[Live example on Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/itsjustluck/pen/NqqYpZ)

Comment: WTF! This saved my day! Thank you. I am guessing this has to do with the shadow dom somehow, and that when referencing these ideas they are somehow not referable when the display: none is being set.

Comment: You're welcome! Its kind weird, because this only applies to clippath in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using only "width" and "height" equals to zero, left a void area where should be the image. However, using `display:content;`  instead `display:none;` works fine, no void area and no image.