# `display: none` vs 0 height and width on a SVG sprite sheet.

Tags: svg, shadow-dom, xlink

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993846/why-does-svg-use-xlinkhref-referencing-an-element-with-clip-path-not-wor) has a really interesting problem at the core:

Setting `display: none` on the SVG containing the SVG sprites (`symbol`s) will make the clip paths that are defined and referenced within unusable, while hiding the SVG using `height: 0; width: 0;` will make them work.

While the question has an answer to fix the immediate problem, it does not answer *why* this works. I am guessing it has something to do with the Shadow DOM: it seems as the ids in the `defs` section are unreferable when `display: none` is set on the container. Could anyone shed some light on the hows and whys in this, preferably with some reference to the SVG or HTML specs?

Comment: The spec says it should work. Browsers disagree and don't support it as it's hard to do while keeping html performance unaffected.

Comment: Great insight. Thanks for shedding some light on this.