# I don't understand how to use local svg file

Tags: html, css, svg

this is the svg
https://gist.github.com/Mautriz/8a936e0d1df136459d2c7f133d9b50d9

It's in a file called "test.svg" inside the same folder of the html

```html
<svg height="400" width="400">
  <use xlink:href="test.svg"></use>
</svg>
```

I have tried with or without xlink, with relative and absolute path, what am I missing ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/068gk45v/. Someone put CSS in the middle of the SVG

Comment: woah thanks, and how do I deal with such a case? Since I think the site where I got it from probably has other cases like this

Comment: I mean, if there's a better way of doing it than manually removing css on every image

Comment: Browser's security models have been tightened recently and local files can't reference other local files any more. Use a web server.

Answer (score 5):

There're different ways you can use SVG into your code. In your particular case, you are trying to use the `SVG Sprites` method.
`<use>` shape has to be defined ON THE PAGE somewhere else. Also match the `xlink:href=` and SVG `path` or `symbol` id.

There're so many different articles on how to use `SVG Sprites`.

1. #### SVGs as Static Images

   `img`, `object`, `embed` specify the source of your svg file.

```
    <img 
        src="equilateral.svg" 
        alt="triangle with all three sides equal"
        height="87px"
        width="100px" />
```

2. #### HTML-Inlined SVG Images

```
    <svg width="300" height="200">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="green" />
    </svg>
```

3. #### CSS Inlined SVG Backgrounds

```
 .img { 
   background-image: url(image.svg);
 }
```

4. #### SVG Sprites | SVG with `use` reference.

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993846/why-does-svg-use-xlinkhref-referencing-an-element-with-clip-path-not-wor).

```
<!-- SVG element  -->

<svg id="svg-test" style="width:0; height:0;">
  <clipPath id="my-clip-1">
    <circle id="circle-1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
  </clipPath>
  <path id="svg-test-reference" clip-path="url(#my-clip-1)" d="M10-39.288h80v80H10z" />
</svg>

<!-- Reference SVG <path> by ID with Use -->

<svg class="svg-item" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <use xlink:href="#svg-test-reference" />
</svg>
```